# Automate an application whose widget descriptions are partially filled in

Tags: pywinauto

I want to automate an application whose widget descriptions are partially filled in.

Sometimes in inpect.exe I only have "Legacy/accessible.Name" or "Legacy/accessible.Description to identify a widget.

Most of the time, only the position of the widget allows you to identify the widget and even sometimes there is only the ToolTip which allows you to identify the widget.

In case I only have Legacy/accessible.Description, how to find the widget in Pywinauto?
[A widget with Legacy/accessible.Description="Play/Record"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd4ta.jpg)

In case I only have the ToolTip, how to find the widget in Pywinauto?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @Artem the question is clear enough to me. Of course, Inspect.exe screenshot would be good to see, but it’s not critical.

Comment: @David Pratmarty the answer would be this is not always possible. But it might be implemented. Is there some public sample apps with such kind of elements?

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov let's say I have a list of elements, how do I filter the elements containing a specific string in the property corresponding to Legacy/accessible.Description?

Comment: Currently there is no way. I need sample app to implement and test this feature. :)